# Angular2: how to handle routing for child modules

Tags: url, angular, path, routes, angular2-routing

i'm developing an Angular2 app and i'd like to have this structure:

- APP ---> Main cointainer ---> First section
- APP ---> Main cointainer ---> Second section
- APP ---> Main cointainer ---> Third section

I would have a module for every level:

- `app.module.ts`
- `main.module.ts`
- `first-section.module.ts`
- `second-section.module.ts`
- `third-section.module.ts`

I tried to create the following files, that represents two levels.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        MainModule,
        routing,
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders,
        LoginService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
Paths['appPaths'] = {
    login: 'login',
    pageNotFound: '**'
};

const appPaths = Paths.appPaths;

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: appPaths.login, component: LoginComponent },
    { path: appPaths.pageNotFound, component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

**main.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MainComponent,
        SomeDirective
    ],
    imports: [
        MainRouting,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        SomeService,
        AuthGuard
    ]
})

export class MainModule {
}
```

**main.routing.ts**

```
Paths['cdcPaths'] = {
    mainBase: ''
    firstPage: 'firstPage',
    secondPage: 'secondPage',
    thirdPage: 'thirdPage',
};

const cdcPaths = Paths.cdcPaths;

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: cdcPaths.mainBase, component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: cdcPaths.firstPage, component: firstPageComponent },
            { path: cdcPaths.secondPage, component: secondPageComponent },
            { path: cdcPaths.thirdPage, component: thirdPageComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: cdcPaths.firstPage, pathMatch: 'full' }
        ]
    }
];

export const MainRouting = RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes);
```

**util.ts**

```
export const Paths: any = {};
```

Could this be the right approach? As you can see i created even different routing files for every module. Could this be a right way to develop?
At this point... how to create the third level?

Comment: LGTM, I have similar setup (see this simplified [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/5b6c26499503c40cf41a7eef0db64172) with one more nested level then your example), and it follows recommendations from [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)...

Comment: With your solution how to programmatically deal with `router.navigate` and paths invoked from other Components?

Comment: @Sasxa i created a new question about Angular2 routing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110827/angular2-router-how-to-correctly-load-children-modules-with-their-own-routing-r. Can you please have a look at it?