# Angular2 router: how to correctly load children modules with their own routing rules

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing, nested-routes, angular2-modules

here is my Angular2 app structure:

[image]

Here is part of my code. The following is the main `module` of the Angular2 app, that imports its routing rules and a child module (`EdgeModule`) and uses some components related to some pages.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        appRouting,
        EdgeModule
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders,
        LoginService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Here is the routing rules for the main module. It have paths to login page and page not found.

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Here is `EdgeModule` that declares the component that it uses and import its own routing rules and 2 child modules (`FirstSectionModule` and `SecondSectionModule`).

**edge.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        EdgeComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        TopbarComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        edgeRouting,
        FirstSectionModule,
        SecondSectionModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard
    ]
})

export class EdgeModule {
}
```

Here is the routing rules for the module that loads, as you can see, topbar and sidebar components.

**edge.routing.ts**

```
Paths['edgePaths'] = {
    firstSection: 'firstSection',
    secondSection: 'secondSection'
};

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: EdgeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: Paths.edgePaths.firstSection, loadChildren: '../somepath/first-section.module#FirstModule' },
            { path: Paths.edgePaths.secondSection, loadChildren: '../someotherpath/second-section.module#SecondModule' },
            { path: '', redirectTo: edgePaths.dashboard, pathMatch: 'full' }
        ]
    }
];

export const edgeRouting = RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes);
```

Finally, this is one of the two child module, that have its components and imports its routing rules.

**first-section.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FirstSectionComponent,
        SomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        firstSectionRouting
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
    ]
})

export class FirstSectionModule {
}
```

These are the routing rules for the pages (components) of `FirstSectionModule`

**first-section.routing.ts**

```
Paths['firstSectionPaths'] = {
    someSubPage: 'some-sub-page',
    someOtherSubPage: 'some-other-sub-page'
};

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { path: Paths.firstSectionPaths.someSubPage, component: someSubPageComponent},
            { path: Paths.firstSectionPaths.someOtherSubPage, component: someOtherSubPageComponent},
            { path: '', component: AnagraficheComponent }
        ]
    }
];

export const firstSectionRouting = RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes);
```

Almost the same happens for `second-section.module.ts` and `second-section.routing.ts` files.

When i run the app the first things that load is the page related to `FirstSectionComponent`, with no sidebar nor topbar.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? There are not errors in the console.

Comment: try removing `FirstSectionModule` and `SecondSectionModule` from `edgeModule` import

Comment: Yes, doing this and also changing the paths in `edge.routing.ts` do the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Anyway it is weird that i had to put runtime paths in the lazying loading of the modules to make the app working...

Comment: I'm trying to create a Plunker, but i cannot to reproduce my situation. Can you help me? https://plnkr.co/edit/HFZWCqoUsHHWcE7jdIWe

Comment: Hello, 
Did you find as solution to that ? 
It's seams like splitting routing config in a sub module was only done to support lazy loading (using loadChildren).
I could not figured out how to put router config in a sub module and plug it's routing config below an existing route of a parent module...

Comment: I did not find something similar to 'loadChildren' that could inform the framework to 'plug' a child module route config at a specific point ...

Answer (score 8):

You can try this using `loadChildren` where the `homeModule`, `productModule`, `aboutModule` have their own route rules.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/areas/home/home.module#homeModule' },
    { path: 'product', loadChildren: 'app/areas/product/product.module#ProductModule' },
    { path: 'drawing', loadChildren: 'app/areas/about/about.module#AboutModule' }
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and the home route rules will be like

```
export const RouteConfig: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomePage },
            { path: 'test/:id', component: Testinfo},
            { path: 'test2/:id', component: Testinfo1},
            { path: 'test3/:id', component: Testinfo2}
        ]
    }
];
```

this is also known as lazy loading the modules.

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

There's a few important things to notice here:
We use the property `loadChildren` instead of component.
We pass a string instead of a symbol to avoid loading the module eagerly.
We define not only the path to the module but the name of the class as well.
There's nothing special about `LazyModule` other than it has its own routing and a component called `LazyComponent`.

Check out this awesome tutorial related to this:
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, anyway the problem with lazy loading ans SystemJS is that these paths doesn't exist when you build your app for production, when you get one minified JS file as output of Gulp's build task.

Comment: did you try adding <base href="/"> in the index.html

Comment: I mean that in the minified JS file I have not references to paths, such as `/lazy/lazy.module`

Answer (score 1):

In your app.routing.ts, there are only 2 routes and no route included to navigate to the Main section (as in the diagram). There needs to be a route entry with loadchildren property so it will load the module for the Main section.

```
routes: Routes = [...
{ 
path: 'main', loadChildren: '<file path>/<Edge module file name>#EdgeModule' 
}
...];
```

This will load the rest of the modules, components routes and everything insite the EdgeModule.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the problem correctly, but here is a small code snippet which I used to generate routes dynamically:

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit() {
     ...
     this._router.config[0].children = myService.getRoutes(); 
     this._router.resetConfig(this._router.config);
     console.debug('Routes:', this._router.config);
     ...
}
```

It is not OOTB solution, but you can get information about current routes.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: ok, show me please how to generate routes dynamically, after application started.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dependency injection problem.
We don't need to inject FirstSectionModule & SecondSectionModule in the edgeModule & about route we can use inside of FirstSectionModule & SecondSectionModule.
So just removing it from edgeModule will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 13 & 13+ version, we can do like:-

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "user",
    loadChildren: () => import("./user/user.module").then((m) => {m.UserModule})
  }
];
```

Comment: How can I write userDetail as a child of user with lazyLoading