# Angular.io routing for Login page and Main view (with nested views) using multiple modules/files

Tags: angular, authentication, router

Using Angular 4's routing with separate files/modules for my features, I'm trying to make my app always show the login screen first then switch to my main view once the user logs in (all routes are guarded by authentication, except the login one).

I created a test app in Plunker, with notes within the app about the functionality I need, as opposed to what's currently happening: 
    https://plnkr.co/edit/MGIGH4xpKZOtgCBl5lam

The problem I've had with most sample code [(like this one)](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#app-routing-ts) is that the component being routed to after login does not have any nested views. I got my app working by putting all the routes in a single file, but I'd prefer splitting up the routes per feature. However, as soon as I do that, things start getting wonky:

- Clicking the login button shows the club component, without being nested in the main-nav's template; plus the club component shows even before authentication is done.
- If I navigate manually by typing 'members' in the url, the member list shows correctly, but when I click on a member, it shows "page not found" instead of the member-detail view

It's close, though -- typing in either "club" or "members" in the url will force the login page to show and when I click the login button, it will then show the correct page, nested in the main-nav view.  Then I can use the main-nav links to flip back and forth between "club" and "members" and logout.

I think the problem may be with the way I'm doing the lazy loading, maybe?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainNavComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'club', loadChildren: 'app/club.module#ClubModule'},
      { path: 'members', loadChildren: 'app/members.module#MembersModule'},
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'club', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  }
];
```

I followed the angular.io routing docs and [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110827/angular2-router-how-to-correctly-load-children-modules-with-their-own-routing-r) to get it working as well as it is, but I can't figure out the last bit that's messed up. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: After quickly reading your question, I dont get what is the problem/question? I tried to see the plnkr but it doenst works. You did well by separating the routes by feature.

Comment: Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gnUlh44vuA2nCNLG9iXb?p=preview

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, my problems are listed in the bulleted list. Also, I was able to get the Plunker working & the problems/questions are noted within the UI too.  Thanks for taking the time to look at it!

Comment: @Teddy, thanks for getting the plunker running - I was able to copy your config.js and index.html to get mine working. Your changes, however, did not fix the routing as I need.  By replacing the ```''``` paths with ```'club'``` and ```'members'```, it puts those component's views at the top level, instead of nested within ```main-nav```.  Now that I've got my Plunker working, which includes more details about where things are not working as needed, would you want to take another shot at it?  I appreciate the time you took to try to help me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were a variety of issues which I addressed and added to the demo below.

1. Do not import the lazy loaded modules into the app module as this causes them to be loaded immediately. This also makes the module routes take precedence over the AppModule routes.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    // ClubModule,
    // MainNavModule,
    // MembersModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. The lazy loaded modules should all behave as there own app so the routes should be configured so that the root component of each module has an empty path.

```js
// club-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: ClubComponent }
];
```

```js
// members-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MembersComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: ':id', component: MemberDetailComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

3. Lastly, the app module should have a default path for the router to resolve to. In my example I had it resolve to the routing module since it is protected by a guard but you could just as easily route it to the login module.

```js
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/main-nav.module#MainNavModule' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

## [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gnUlh44vuA2nCNLG9iXb?p=preview)

Comment: Yay, that's PERFECT!!  Thanks so much for the bit of explanation to go along with the changes, too.

Comment: @SherriM thanks for this answer, in my case MainNavModule has children that "loadChildren" does that work?

Comment: Amazing answer.  I am starting a new app for my company and I'm verifying best practices for each part of the project for maintainability and functionality.  This is a very clean, to the point solution.  Thanks for the answer.